# Why this oneliner - echo "hello" | perl -e '<>; print' does not work

Tags: perl

I am still new to Perl and had problem to understand why this one liner does not work.

My understanding is that it read from input to `$_` and then print should be able to print it out but it does not wait for input from keyboard and does not print anything.

```
[admin@mb125:~/src/test/scripting] : echo "hello" | perl -e '<>; print'
```

I know if I do `print` before `<>` it works, like following

```
[admin@mb125:~/src/test/scripting] : echo "hello" | perl -e 'print <>'
hello
```

Can anyone explain for me why first one liner does not work ?

thanks

Comment: If you add warnings with `-w` it will tell you why it prints nothing.

Comment: It warns you that `$_` is uninitialized, it doesn't say _why_ it's not set, which is the thing he's confused about because he thought `<>` was equivalent to `$_ = <>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<>` without an assignment only assigns to `$_` automatically if it's used like this:

```
while (<>)
```

Since you used it outside `while`, this special case doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one-liner that looks like it will do what you're looking for:

```
echo "world" | xargs perl -e 'print "Hello " . (shift @ARGV) . "\n"; '
```

A Perl script takes parameters from the command line and stores them in the special variable @ARGV. So if you have a Perl script that you call with `"perl myscript.pl foo bar baz"`, @ARGV will contain `['foo','bar','baz']`. You can then use array operators like `shift, pop` or `$array[$n]` to access the data.

xargs (in this case) takes the parameters piped into it and passes them on to the Perl script like they were command-line arguments. It's a pretty handy function.

Oh, and if you do this you have to have the parentheses around `(shift @ARGV)` . Otherwise Perl throws a `"not an ARRAY reference"` error when it gets to `"\n"`, or at least mine does.